# Best way to iterate through unknown number of lists in general?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Given a programming language that supports iteration through lists i.e.

```
for element in list do
    ...
```

If we have a program that takes a dynamic number of lists as input, `list[1] ... list[n]` (where `n` can take any value), what is the best way to iterate through every combination of elements in these lists?

e.g. `list[1] = [1,2]`, `list[2] = [1,3]` then we iterate through `[[1,1], [1,3], [2,1], [2,3]]`.

My ideas that I don't think are very good:

1) Create a big product of these lists into `list_product` (e.g. in Python you could use `itertools.product()` multiple times) and then iterate over `list_product`. Problem is that this requires us to store a (potentially huge) iterable.

2) Find the product of the length of all the lists, total_length and do something along the lines of the following by using a modular arithmetic type idea.

```
len_lists = [len(list[i]) for i in [1..n]]
total_length = Product(len_lists)
for i in [1 ... total_length] do
    total = i-1
    list_index = [1...n]
    for j in [n ... 1] do
        list_index[j] = IntegerPartOf(total / Product([1:j-1]))
        total = RemainderOf(total / Product([1:j-1]))
    od
    print list_index
od
```

where the `list_index` are then printed for all different combinations.

Is there a better way with regards to speed (don't care so much about readability)?

Comment: Can the sublists have different numbers of elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Create a big product of these lists into list_product (e.g. in Python you could use itertools.product() multiple times) and then iterate over list_product. Problem is that this requires us to store a (potentially huge) iterable.

The point of `itertools` (and iterators in general) is that they do not construct their entire result at once, but create and return terms from the result one at a time. So if you have a list of lists `ListOfLists` and you want all tuples containing one element from each list in it, do use

```
for elt in itertools.product(*ListOfLists):
   ...
```

Note that **you only need to call `product` once.** It's simple and efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product` without needing to materialize a list:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lol = [[1,2],[1,3]]
>>> product(*lol)
<itertools.product object at 0xaa414b4>
>>> for x in product(*lol):
...     print x
...     
(1, 1)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
```

As for performance, it's very easy to spend more time thinking of ways to optimize it than you can ever hope to gain from the optimizations.  If you're doing anything inside the loop at all, then it's pretty likely that the iteration overhead itself is negligible.  (Most common exception is a tight numerical loop, in which case you should try to do it numpythonically instead.)

My advice would be to use `itertools.product` and get on with your day.